# Image displayed as a string of digits and chars in Bootstrap carousel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

An `image_tag` is used to display an image in `Rails 4.2` app for `Bootstrap carousel`.

```
<img src="<%=image_tag 'person_erp.jpg'%>" alt="First Slide">
```

The image `person_erp.jpg` resides under `/assets/images/`. On the web page, it shows a string of digits and chars instead of the image.

[image]

Here is the `html` code:

```
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="active item">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <img src="<%=image_tag 'person_erp.jpg'%>" alt="First Slide">
                      <h3><%=t('Simply Your Business')%></h3>
                      <p>
                        <%=t('Simply Your Business Details')%>
                      </p>
                      <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
                        <%= link_to t('Learn More'), SUBURI + signups_new_path, :class => "btn btn-success btn-md" %>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                 .....
            </div>
```

Tried the following and none of them works

```
<img src="person_erp.jpg" alt="First Slide">
<img src="/assets/images/person_erp.jpg" alt="First Slide">
```

What's missing with our image src above?

Comment: <%=image_tag 'person_erp.jpg', alt: "First Slide" %> works for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have wrapped your image tags into each other.

`image_tag` helper method generates `<img src="...">` markup so you probably do not need the extra one.

Change this line

```
<img src="<%=image_tag 'person_erp.jpg'%>" alt="First Slide">
```

to

```
<%= image_tag 'person_erp.jpg', alt: 'First Slide' %>
```